# Why do I get a segmentation fault while trying to use lock routines?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, locking, openmp, master-slave

I have `tasklist_GRAD` which is an array of function pointers and I want to use the `lock` routines in order to execute the `tasks` (defined in another `module`).
Here is the `subroutine` I implemented:

```
  module app_management
  use OMP_LIB
  use tasks
  implicit none
  !etats
  integer, parameter:: STATE_RUNNING=0
  integer, parameter:: STATE_READY=1
  integer, parameter:: STATE_WAITING=2
!!$  integer, parameter:: STATE_INACTIVE=3 

contains
  subroutine management(tasklist_GRAD,var)
    INTEGER ::ff
    type(tcb)::self
    type(variables)::var 
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer, external :: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS    
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::threads_list !liste contenant les nums des threads workers 
    integer,dimension(100)::threads_list_all !liste contenant les nums des threads workers dans l'ordre selon les tâches  
    integer,dimension(3)::threads_list_part1 ! 3 premières tâches
    integer,dimension(16)::threads_list_part3 ! le reste des tâches
    integer::threads_list_part2    ! 4 eme tâche
    INTEGER(KIND=omp_lock_kind), SAVE :: lock

    CALL omp_init_lock (lock)

    !=======================================================================================================================================================
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,threads_list_all,nthreads,ff) &
    !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master,threads_list,lock) &
    !$OMP SHARED(threads_list_part1,threads_list_part2,threads_list_part3)
    num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread 
    nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads

    Choisircese: select case (var%ww_t)

    case(0)  !  Old CESE


       !Thread Application Master (numero 1)
       if (num_thread==1) then
          do ff=1,3 ! 3 tâches
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true. ) then ! Si tâche attribuée 
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff) ! égalité de pointeurs 
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do
       end if
       
       do while(.not.OMP_test_lock(lock))
          !Threads workers
          !$OMP DO PRIVATE(ff)
          do ff=1,3 
             call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
             tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
          end do
          !$OMP END DO 
       end do
       do ff=1,3 
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_RUNNING) then
             tasklist_GRAD(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING   
          end if
       end do



       !Thread Master (numero 0)
       if (num_thread==0) then 
          if(var%pas_t.eq.2)then
             var%u_prime_t(2) = var%tab0_t(2,2)+var%dt_t/2.0d0*var%grad_x_u_t(2)!d_t_u(2)
             var%u_prime_t(var%cpt_t-1) = var%tab0_t(var%cpt_t-1,2)+var%dt_t/2.0d0*var%grad_t_u_t(var%cpt_t-1)
             var%u_prime_t(1) = var%tab0_t(1,2)+var%dt_t/2.0d0*var%grad_t_u_t(1)
             var%u_prime_t(var%cpt_t) = var%tab0_t(var%cpt_t,2)+var%dt_t/2.0d0*var%grad_t_u_t(var%cpt_t)

             var%u_prime_plus_t(1)= (var%u_prime_t(2)-var%tab_t(1,2))/(var%dx_t/2.0d0)
             var%u_prime_moins_t(1)=-(var%u_prime_t(1)-var%tab_t(1,2))/(var%dx_t/2.0d0)
             var%u_prime_plus_t(var%cpt_t)= (var%u_prime_t(var%cpt_t)-var%tab_t(var%cpt_t,2))/(var%dx_t/2.0d0)
             var%u_prime_moins_t(var%cpt_t)= -(var%u_prime_t(var%cpt_t-1)-var%tab_t(var%cpt_t,2))/(var%dx_t/2.0d0)
          endif
       end if

  

       !Thread Master (numero 0)
       if (num_thread==0) then
          call  tasks_ready_master(4)%f_ptr(self,var)
          tasks_ready_master(4)%state=STATE_RUNNING             
       end if
       !$OMP BARRIER

       if (num_thread==0) then 

          !-------Condition cyclique sur les gradients
          if(var%pas_t.eq.1)then
             var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t)=var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t-1)!w0(u_prime_plus(cpt),u_prime_moins(cpt),2.0d0,0.01d0)
             var%grad_x_u_t(1)=var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t)
          endif

          if(var%pas_t.eq.2)then
             var%grad_x_u_t(1)=var%grad_x_u_t(2)!w0(u_prime_plus(1),u_prime_moins(1),0.0d0,1.0d0)!0.99d0)!
             var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t)=var%grad_x_u_t(1)!w0(u_prime_plus(cpt),u_prime_moins(cpt),0.0d0,1.0d0)!0.99d0)!
          endif
       end if


       !------- En vrai, pas retesté avec ce type de gradient. M'est avis que ça ne fonctionne sans doute pas


    case(2)  !  W2

       !Thread Application Master (numero 1)
       if (num_thread==1) then
          do ff=5,20 ! 16 tâches 
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true.) then
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff)
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do
       end if

       do while(.not.OMP_test_lock(lock))
          !Threads workers
          !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC) PRIVATE(ff)
          do ff=5,20 
             call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
             tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
          end do
          !$OMP END DO 
       end do
       do ff=5,20 
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_RUNNING) then
             tasklist_GRAD(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING   
          end if
       end do



       if (num_thread==0) then 
          var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t)=var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t-1)
          var%grad_x_u_t(1)=var%grad_x_u_t(var%cpt_t)
       end if
    end select choisircese
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
    CALL omp_destroy_lock (lock)


  end subroutine management
end module app_management
```

I get a `segmentation fault - invalid memory reference` error.
It is due to the fact that I added the following part to the code:

```
do while(.not.OMP_test_lock(lock))
          !Threads workers
          !$OMP DO PRIVATE(ff)
          do ff=1,3 
             call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
             tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
          end do
          !$OMP END DO 
       end do
       do ff=1,3 
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_RUNNING) then
             tasklist_GRAD(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING   
          end if
       end do
```

For example, I have 16 `tasks` and 4 `threads` (only 2 `workers` which mean only 2 will execute the `tasks`). I wanted  to implement this using `lock` routines that's why I added the mentioned part. Whenever a thread between the workers is free, it should execute the first element of `tasklist_GRAD`. The `master` thread should only if a worker is free or not.
I am still discovering the `lock` routines.

Comment: I assume you have tried -fcheck=all and similar? Beyond that with a complete code it is going to be very difficult for us to help you debug - what you are doing is quite complicated and, at least for me, very non-intuitive.

Comment: I do see some worrying `integer, external :: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS` and I don't see neither `implicit none` nor `include 'omp_lib.h'` or better `use omp_lib` and not any definition of the `omp_test_lock()` function... Please consider fixing that first

Comment: @Gilles I edited my question in order to show you the missing points. It's a whole module containing the subroutine management.

Comment: Well I very much doubt it is the problem, but if you use the module you don't need to (and shouldn't) redeclare the functions as external returning integers. The module has already done this for you (and more). But as a first check get rid of that line and see if things change.

Comment: @IanBush even when I get rid of `external`, I still have the same problem. I hope you understood what I'm trying to to using lock routines. For example if I have 16 tasks and 2 workers, I want the worker 1 to execute the first task and the worker 2 to execute the second task. The worker who finishes his execution first will move to the next task. I am confused.  So we can have the 3 first tasks being executed by only one worker. It depend on the time spent on the execution.